# Вызвать метод UserControl из главного окна

Tags: c#, wpf

В главном окне есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую должен вызваться метод , который есть в UserControl

```
public void ShopControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _launcher.Initialize();
    }
```

Код контрола в MainWindow.xaml

```
<controls:ShopControl x:Name="ShopTab"
                      Margin="-4,60,0,4"
                      Foreground="#FFFFFFFF"
                      Visibility="Hidden" />
```

Код кнопки главного окна

```
private void shopBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShopTab.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Подскажите, как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, если совсем по-простому, то так:

1. У кнопки указываете `Click="OnButtonClick"`
2. В окне у `UserControl`'а устанавливаете имя через `Name`:

   ```
   <local:MyUserControl Name="XYZ">...</local:MyUserControl>
   ```
3. Создаёте метод `OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`, в нём вызовите `XYZ.Method()`. Позаботьтесь о том, чтобы метод был публичным.

---

Да, если метод называется у вас `Control_Loaded`, что-то тут не так.

Comment: Обновила вопрос

Comment: @Елизавета: Ну, первая часть у вас есть. Вторая есть? Используйте имя в третьей.

Comment: Не совсем поняла(

Comment: @Елизавета: Ну, обработчик клика по кнопке у вас есть, он у вас называется `shopBtn_Click`, окей? Затем, у вас в XAML'е должен быть ваш `UserControl`, но вы не привели ваш XAML, и мне приходится угадывать, как он там выглядит. Так вот этому самому `UserControl`'у в XAML нужно дать имя, чтобы обратиться к нему.

Comment: Прошу прощения, обновила вопрос

Comment: Вопрос решен, спасибо!

Comment: @Елизавета: Вот и хорошо. Пожалуйста!